# How can there be a change in momentum with no appearent external force?

Tags: forces, momentum, conservation-laws

Momentum is conserved in a system with no external force.
So then let's imagine a particle of mass m being dropped from the surface of Earth's atmosphere such that there is a significant change in G between its initial and final position.
a change in G, then, means a change in acceleration, which means a change in force which then means a change in momentum.
I can see that G is indeed changing in time and so momentum must also be changing, but I don't see how G is changing without there being an external force.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming by $G$ you actually mean $g$, local gravitational acceleration ($9.8 \,\mathrm{m/s^2}$ on Earth's surface) and not the universal gravitation constant, usually denoted $G$ ($6.7\cdot 10^{-11} \mathrm{N~m^2~kg^{-2}}$), which does not change.

If that's the case, your question is

> a change in $g$, then, means a change in acceleration, which means a change in force which then means a change in momentum.

There is a little bit of confusion here.  Even a constant force will cause a constant acceleration; so a constant, uniform gravity field will cause continuous acceleration (constantly increasing speed *v*).  Since momentum is *mv*, this means momentum is changing constantly even under a constant force (and accompanying constant acceleration).

The fact that the local value of $g$ changes in your scenario does not add anything significant, except that the acceleration and force will increase instead of being constant, and the momentum will increase more quickly than it would have in a constant gravity field.

> I can see that *g* is indeed changing in time and so momentum must also be changing

Acceleration does not have to change in order for momentum to change.  As discussed, a constant *g* will cause a continuous increase in speed and momentum.

> but I don't see how *g* is changing without there being an external force

The external force is gravity.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I now realise I had it mixed up- I thought momentum was a change in force when in fact, force is a change in momentum.

Comment: More exactly, force is proportional to the *rate* of change in momentum. Newton's 2nd law states exactly this.  Thus, a block sliding down a hill with heavy friction (more force) will slow down and stop more quickly than on a hill with only light friction.

Answer (score 1):

Momentum is conserved in a closed system. When you consider the object that is falling and the earth as a single system, the combined momenta will be given by:
\begin{equation}
\vec{P}_{\text{total}}=\sum_i\vec{p}_i=\vec{p}_\text{earth}+\vec{p}_\text{object}
\end{equation}

You can check that if these objects follow Newton's third law, the total momentum $\vec{P}_\text{total}$ is conserved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You've got to be careful about how you define the system in order to determine whether or not it is subjected to an external force.

If you define the system as the particle of mass $m$ alone, then the force of gravity is an external force and momentum is not conserved. If you define the system as the particle plus the Earth, then gravity is an internal force and momentum is conserved. But it is the momentum of the particle plus the Earth that is conserved. Not the individual momenta of the particle and the Earth.

Keep in mind that as the particle accelerates towards the Earth, the Earth is at the same time accelerating towards the particle.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Gravity is an external force as far as the object is concerned.
2. Any (net) force, constant or varying will change the momentum of the particle.
3. The total change in momentum that occurs over a time period $\Delta t$ exactly equals to the area under the curve of the force vs time graph. $$ \Delta p = \int_{\Delta t} F\,{\rm d}t$$
4. In the presence of a gravity gradient, where $F \propto \tfrac{1}{r^2} $, the above holds, just as it would if the force was constant.